# How To make Map Pins Animate drop? Swift 2.2 IOS 9

Tags: swift, mkmapview, ios9, mapkit, mkannotation

I have a basic setup here of a map in my view, I'm trying to make the pins animate a drop...Just like when you press & hold in the maps app and the pin drops to the location. So when I get in the view all the pins will animate a drop to their location and I really dont know how to do that . If anyone can guide me to the correct code I need to add that will be great!

Here is the Current Code I have :

```
   class FirstViewController: UIViewController,MKMapViewDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate{



@IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!





    let locationManager = CLLocationManager()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad() 

        self.locationManager.delegate = self
        self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        self.locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        self.locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
        self.mapView.showsUserLocation = true 


   let LitzmanLocation = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(32.100668,34.775192)
        // Drop a pin
        let Litzman = MKPointAnnotation()
        Litzman.coordinate = LitzmanLocation
        Litzman.title = "Litzman Bar"
        Litzman.subtitle = "Nemal Tel Aviv St'"
        mapView.addAnnotation(Litzman)}

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    //Dispose of resources that can be re created.

        }

    //Mark:

    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation])

    {
        let location = locations.last

        let center = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: location!.coordinate.latitude, longitude: location!.coordinate.longitude)

        let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: center, span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.1, longitudeDelta: 0.1))

        self.mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)

        self.locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
    }

    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: NSError)
    {
        print("Errors: " + error.localizedDescription)
    }
```

Comment: You need to be more specific in what you're asking for, and ensure that your code is formatted correctly - otherwise it's going to be difficult to help you

Comment: @AIBlue Where are u my friend?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Before all I am not maintaining any standards and I just have one of the solution for your problem and I am learning **swift** and **mapKit** by solving others problems.

Here I have given some sample code and I have added **mapView** and  **UITapGestureRecognizer** through the Object library.

***For adding annotation like dropping from top***

```
pinView!.animatesDrop = true
```

in the **viewForAnnotation** delegation method.And **addAnnotation** method will call to add the annotation when you **tap** on the map.

***For animating all the annotation***

I have implemented **regionDidChangeAnimated** delegate method and just remove and add again all the annotations.

```
import UIKit
import MapKit
import CoreLocation

class MapViewController: UIViewController,  MKMapViewDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!

let locationManager = CLLocationManager()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    print("viewDidLoad")
    self.mapView.delegate = self
    self.locationManager.delegate = self
    self.locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    self.locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    self.mapView.showsUserLocation = true

    let locationData = [
        //Walker Art Gallery
        ["name": "Walker Art Gallery",
            "latitude": 12,
            "longitude": 79],
        //Liver Buildings
        ["name": "Liver Buildings",
            "latitude": 13,
            "longitude": 77],
        //St George's Hall
        ["name": "St George's Hall",
            "latitude": 14,
            "longitude": 77]
    ]
    var annotations = [MKPointAnnotation]()
    for each in locationData {
        let latitude = CLLocationDegrees(each["latitude"] as! Double)
        let longitude = CLLocationDegrees(each["longitude"] as! Double)
        let coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude)
        let name = each["name"] as! String
        let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
        annotation.coordinate = coordinate
        annotation.title = "\(name)"
        annotations.append(annotation)
    }
    mapView.addAnnotations(annotations)
}

func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, viewForAnnotation annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
    print("viewForAnnotation \(annotation.title)")
    if annotation is MKUserLocation {
        return nil
    }
    let reuseID = "pin"
    var pinView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier(reuseID) as? MKPinAnnotationView
    if(pinView == nil) {
        pinView = MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: reuseID)
        pinView!.canShowCallout = true
        pinView!.animatesDrop = true
    }
    return pinView
}

@IBAction func addAnnotation(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    if sender.state == .Ended {
        let location = sender.locationInView(mapView)
        let coordinate = mapView.convertPoint(location,toCoordinateFromView: mapView)

        let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
        annotation.coordinate = coordinate
        mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)
    }
}

func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, regionDidChangeAnimated animated: Bool) {
    print("regionDidChangeAnimated")
    let annotations = self.mapView.annotations
    self.mapView.removeAnnotations(annotations)
    self.mapView.addAnnotations(annotations)
} 
}
```

**EDIT**

For your case in the viewDidLoad method add this

```
self.mapView.delegate = self
```

For annotating the MKAnnotation you have to implement the below delegate method

```
 //Annotation view
func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, viewForAnnotation annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
    if annotation is MKUserLocation {
        return nil
    }
    let reuseID = "pin"
    var pinView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier(reuseID) as? MKPinAnnotationView
    if(pinView == nil) {
        pinView = MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: reuseID)
        pinView!.canShowCallout = true
        pinView!.animatesDrop = true
    }
    return pinView
}
```

After for annotating all the annotation you have to implement below delegate method.

```
 func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, regionDidChangeAnimated animated: Bool) {
    let annotations = self.mapView.annotations
    self.mapView.removeAnnotations(annotations)
    self.mapView.addAnnotations(annotations)
}
```

And I am assuming you know how to add annotation on map tap...

**EDIT2**

Here is what you need my friend.

In the viewDidLoad add one **notification observer** as follows.

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(didBecomeActive), name: UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification, object: nil)
```

And lastly change that **regionDidChangeAnimated** to **didBecomeActive** as below

```
func didBecomeActive() {
    let annotations = self.mapView.annotations
    self.mapView.removeAnnotations(annotations)
    self.mapView.addAnnotations(annotations)
}
```

Comment: Firstly,Thank you for taking your time to help :) , Secondly i would like to know if i **Dont** wanna change my code entirely and just add the functionality that all my annotations will animate  do i just copy This code From :       }let reuse ID = Pin . To : return PinView . In my code?

Comment: it didnt work for me...... Can you try and implement only pinView.!anmiatesDrop = true to my code without changing it entirleyl please?

Comment: Ah thanks , its much more clearer to me now what to do. Im at a little vacation and will test this one in 2 days and report back !

Comment: Ok i tested it but it drops everytime i just move around in the map and not only once i open the map view... do u know how to fix this? thx

Answer (score 0):

In Objective C:

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation
 {

if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[MKUserLocation class]])
    return nil;

// Handle any custom annotations.
if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[MKPointAnnotation class]])
{
    // Try to dequeue an existing pin view first.
    MKPinAnnotationView *pinView = (MKPinAnnotationView*)[mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:@"CustomPinAnnotationView"];
    if (!pinView)
    {
        // If an existing pin view was not available, create one.
        pinView = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"CustomPinAnnotationView"];
        pinView.canShowCallout = YES;
        pinView.animatesDrop = YES;
        pinView.pinTintColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    } else {
        pinView.annotation = annotation;
    }
    return pinView;
}
return nil;
}
```